# Jodit: when launching editor text in editor is centered and background color selection disappears

Tags: css, jodit

I am adding jodit editor to a page of a site I run, but when I do so the cursor (inside the editor) is centered and when you start typing it also is centered.

I tried adding a CSS defintion `.editor { text-align: left; }` but that doesn't change things.

Less important secondary question: before adding the editor I had a background color defined for the textarea which disappears when I add the editor. How do I select a bg color for the editor? I tried doing so on the homepage of Jodit (https://xdsoft.net/jodit/play.html?currentTab=Themes) but even when I change it there it does not change for me (at least not in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> .jodit-container {
> text-align: left;
> }

or `text-align: initial;`
You probably have some global css `text-align: center` which is also applied to the editor. I don't know if you applied the `editor` class to the editor yourself, but the default doesn't have that class.